# iOS managing AVPlayer buffer prompt

Tags: ios, avplayer

I use `AVPlayer` to play a video that is on the internet. So my question is how can I give proper prompt to the user when he needs to wait? (e.g. an animating `UIActivityIndicatorView` whenever he needs to wait for the player to load some more data or seek to a specific time)

I spinning the `UIActivityIndicatorView` whenever I set a new `playerItem` to my `AVPlayer`, then I observe `status` of the `playerItem`, when it becomes `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`, I stop the spinning and start play. So whenever a new `playerItem` is set on my `AVPlayer`, a spinning will be there until it is ready to play.

I also want to give my user the spinning when he needs to wait for the `playerItem` to load more buffer when network connection is bad. I tried observing `playbackBufferEmpty` and `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` but did not work as I expected. I also messed with the `rate` property of my `AVPlayer`, still not work quite well.